# How to make input type="range" trigger an overflow scroll?

Tags: javascript, html

I have an input type="range" that is bigger then its parent. I want to make it scroll when the slider-thumb exits the parent width.

Here is an example, when you exceed the parent width there should be a scroll. How can I do that?

http://jsbin.com/ikemo4/edit

Please note that input type="range" will only work in WebKit browsers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The very simple option is to use the *oninput* event and, assuming your values and widths are accurately represented by the fiddle, when the value of the range increases past the width of the container manipulate the *scrollLeft* by *rangeValue - parentWidth*.  I achieved this in your jsBin example using the following code:

```
var rng = document.getElementById("range");

rng.oninput = function () {
    this.parentNode.scrollLeft = this.value - 400;
}
```

And the result can be demoed [here](http://jsbin.com/ikemo4/3/).  You might want to tweak it slightly to get the desired affect.

Another option would be to check if the value is greater than a certain amount and scroll the box fully to the right.  When it goes back the other way, scroll fully to the left.

Comment: Thank you, it works but the slider just stays there blocked when it reaches the 400 value. I guess that I will have to tweak it...

Comment: @Mircea: the slider moves but gives the appearance that it doesn't because the container is scrolling by the same amount.  You could either tweak it or go with the other option I suggested, scrolling the full amount after passing a certain threshold.